# Issue with x509 certificate binding to a port after the computer restart

Tags: windows-7, restart, x509, netsh

I use command line in c# to bind an x509 certificate to a port as follows
 `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash={1} appid={2} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

It works fine. But if I restart the computer, I will need to remove the certificate from the port and rebind it again. Why? Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hey. Did you ever manage to find or resolve the issue?